# Rails: how to test should_render_template [or similar] for full view path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, functional-testing, shoulda

OK, lets say I'm rendering a view from an oddball path, think:

```
prepend_view_path 'app/custom_views'
```

I'd like to test that the view gets rendered from this path like:

```
should_render_template 'app/custom_views/controller/action'
```

However this matcher only works on the last bits "controller/action".

How can I test that the file rendered has the path, including the 'custom_views'?

Alternately, how can I test which view path was actually used?